# Redesign the existing table by adding more fields or another linked table or something totally different?

Tags: database-design

I have a table structure with columns `id`, `user`, and a dozen of other columns. I have to opt my users to select which day they want to receive the notifications and I can't make up my mind about how to do that.

I don't want to just add 7 more columns to the existing table as that just seems like a bad practice.

I thought of adding another table and then link these two together, but this would include *a lot of rework* on the existing code (and the speed in which I have to deliver this solution is a great factor).

I also thought of for example adding just one column to the existing table which would have the 7 character string like for example `1000100` which would basically mean accept the notification on *monday* and *friday* (you get the point - the position of the 1 or 0 in the array determines if that day I should send the notification to that email.

Can you suggest what would you do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add another table. If adding one simple table is a lot of work, then you are doing something wrong.

```
create table user_notification_preference (
  user_id bigint not null references user (id),
  day_of_week smallint not null check (day_of_week between 0 and 6),

  primary key (user_id, day_of_week)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not do this:

> I also thought of for example adding just one column to the existing
>   table which would have the 7 character string like for example 1000100
>   which would basically mean accept the notification on monday and
>   friday (you get the point - the position of the 1 or 0 in the array
>   determines if that day I should send the notification to that email.

You are working in a relational database environment not a C# program, if you find your self placing logic or code in a column something is wrong.

You simply should introduce a new table that has a userid, and a date or days of when they plan to get notification - simple one to many relationship.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Below is my original answer, and I now realize how bad it is.  DO NOT follow this pattern.  I'd delete it, but I've seen it in so many places that it must be a common anti-pattern.  I'm keeping it up, with this warning NOT to use it, so that future visitors can see, as I do now, why this is bad.

All of the expert advice I've read since Neil McGuinan commented on this answer indicate that ***his*** approach is the better one. Here's one good article that explains why: http://geekswithblogs.net/darrengosbell/archive/2006/03/12/KVPsInDatabaseDesign.aspx

The reason our solution "worked for us" is that we had a process that pivots the KVP data to produce a table with the structure you'd expect - may columns for the attributes.  It's an unnecessary overhead that could have been avoided if we'd known this when we setit up and just created a separate table with columns for attributes.  You don't want to go down the path we took.  It's messy.

**/Edit**

---

I'd set up a new table named Attributes, then an in-between (foreign key) table named CustomerAttributes.  Then you don't have to ever add columns again to add attributes to your customer.

**Attributes:**

```
AttributeId   AttributeName
-----------------------------
1             PreferredNotificationDayOfMonth
2             FavoriteColor
etc...
```

**CustomerAttributes**

```
CustomerId   AttributeId   AttributeValue
1            1             5
1            2             Blue
2            1             1
2            2             Red
```

Reasoning: (Layman's description)   Altering a column is a lot more risky than adding a record to a database table, so if you can shift the attributes into rows rather than columns, [you reduce your future maintenance headaches](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Minimize_redesign_when_extending_the_database_structure).

Comment: what type would I have to set the AttributeValue then? Cause as you also posted in the example it can contain numbers, strings, even booleans in my case.

Comment: It really depends, but I've used two approaches.  One is to store everything as varchar values and convert in code.  Extra overhead in code, no validation at the database level, but there is some trade-off in added simplicity.  The other option changes the tables to that the Attributes table has a Type column. (1= integer, 2= decima, 3=string, 4 = abit (boolean), etc) and then have the CustomerAttributes table contain extra fields. (BoolValue, IntValue, DecimalValue, StringValue, DateTimeValue, etc.).  I used that design once to good results, but there's also a trade-off in wasted storage.

Comment: It really is a matter of preference.  Both approaches have merits, and are better long-term than a design where you have to add columns.  Most databases have maximum column limits.  I actually got stuck rewriting a rather complex project because a previous developer went with an approach that added extra columns, and we hit that limit less than a year after she wrote the dumb thing.  Once you hit that wall, it's easy to see the benefit to using a Properties table as described above.

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan - Thank you. Did not know that. I'll be researching that today. It worked for us, however, so I'm surprised but not too surprised. Do you have recommended reading on the topic?

Comment: @DavidStratton I would check out the SQL Anti-Patterns book. The author is active on this site, but I can't remember his name at the moment.

Comment: @Nikola - You may want to view Niel's comments and answer, then do some research of your own before implementing this.  I wasn't aware that this is an anti-pattern, and I don't know enough to confirm or refute his statement, but he sounds more knowledgeable than me on this.

Comment: @Nikola - I did some resesarch of my own, and now Neil is absolutely right.  I hadn't thought of it, but we DID see performance issues, and wound up taking extra steps to create a de-normalized view based on the KVP's, which we export to a table, and we do our actual lookups on the de-normalized table because the KVP IS a nightmare.. A lot of overhead because I'm following an anti-pattern. It's been so long since the de-normalizing process was set up I forgot about it.  Please do NOT use my suggstion.  http://geekswithblogs.net/darrengosbell/archive/2006/03/12/KVPsInDatabaseDesign.aspx

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan - I want to thank you again.  We were starting down this road on some critical systems, and I think your post and downvote saved us from making a huge mistake early enough in the process that it helped us to avoid a lot of re-work in the future.  I can't thank you enough.